# Export windows events to evt file for last 7 days

Tags: powershell

Hard to believe I just spent an hour searching the net and not able to find an answer to what seems like a simple request.

All I want to do is get the last 7 days of the Windows System and Application events and export each to a specific folder as a file in evt format; so not csv or xml.

Is there a simple way to do this with only a couple of lines of code using any version of powershell? So far I tried with Get-WinEvent, Get-EventLog and the method below but none of them do what I want.

What I have right now is:

```
$logFileName = "System"
$exportFileName = $logFileName + (get-date -f yyyyMMdd) + ".evt"
$logFile = Get-WmiObject Win32_NTEventlogFile | Where-Object {$_.logfilename -eq $logFileName} | Where-Object {$_.TimeCreated -ge $filterDate}
$logFile.backupeventlog($defaultDest + "\" + "EventLogs\" + $exportFileName) | Out-Null
```

But for some reason this either gives me an error or I get no results.

Now this seems to output the correct results:

`$logFile = Get-WinEvent -LogName System | Where-Object {$_.TimeCreated -ge $filterDate}`

...but how can I export it in evt format? I tried it in the example above but I get an error:

> Method invocation failed because
> [System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventLogRecord] does not contain a
> method named 'backupeventlog'.

Comment: Looks like you just modified the example on [this](https://expert-advice.org/powershell/how-to-export-windows-event-logs-with-powershell-script/) site, but you never define `$logFileName`. Try defining that as the full file path to the System log file and see if that works better for you.

Comment: I have that but for some reason didn't include it in my example. But I keep getting "You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I didn't scroll over far enough in your code. The issue is that the WMI object that is returned does not have a `$_.TimeCreated` property, so when you filter `Where-Object {$_.TimeCreated -ge $filterDate}` it will never return anything. The command pertains to the log file itself, not the events within the log, you cannot remove events this way. You would have to backup the log, and then remove events from within the backup somehow.

Comment: Seems we can export no problem to csv while filtering the number of days but not to evt? There has to be a way. I can get all the events to evt format so there has to be a way to just filter it to the last 7 days

Comment: I realize you don't like the answer, but it's true that PowerShell cannot do what you're asking. You could use wevtutil to do it, but I am not familiar with that process. Check [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c8c0a874-d573-49bf-9c04-2dc546dba9d6/take-backup-of-event-log-as-evtx-file-using-powershell?forum=ITCG) for reference.

Comment: Ok thanks. I've settled for the xml format as follows: ```get-winevent -FilterHashtable @{LogName="System";level=1,2,3,4,5;starttime=((get-date).AddDays(-7))} | Export-CliXml```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work without error to export to evtx, with an xpath query using ticks (10,000 ticks = 1 millisecond) (/ow means overwrite):

```
wevtutil.exe epl Security SecurityLog7Days.evtx /q:'*[System[TimeCreated[timediff(@SystemTime) <= 6048000000 ]]]' /ow:true
```

Ref:  [Exporting Events with Wevtutil Using a Time-Based Query – Cloud Azzurri](https://cloudazzurri.com/2008/11/28/exporting-event-logs-with-wevtutilexe-using-a-time-based-query/)

```
[timespan]7.  # note the period


Days              : 7
Hours             : 0
Minutes           : 0
Seconds           : 0
Milliseconds      : 0
Ticks             : 6048000000000
TotalDays         : 7
TotalHours        : 168
TotalMinutes      : 10080
TotalSeconds      : 604800
TotalMilliseconds : 604800000
```

A filtered query after the fact:

```
get-winevent -FilterHashtable @{ path = 'SecurityLog7Days.evtx'; endtime = '3/23' }
```